# Show progess bar dialog when submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'd like to show a popup jquery styled if possible on every postback, for example saying Loading... I don't know how to accomplish that nor which tecnologyes use. I want to put the code on a super class so that I need to code only once. In principle I'd like that when I press the submit button, the page hides itself.
Hope you help me.

Edited:
It should be something like that. I have a page, I open a jquery dialog with an iframe on it and with a submit button. When I submit the form the dialog with the form must hide and a new dialog saying loading... have to appear; when the operations finishes this dialog must hides.

Comment: When you make post back using Ajax, or just post back and waiting for the next page ?

Comment: Just postack saying loading... or sending... and wait for the next page. The page where I press the button in, must be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using the `onsubmit` trigger on the `form` of you page as:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return disableForm(this);">
 ...
</form>
```

an on javascript what I do is that on the first submit click I let the submit, and close/open the dialogs that I like. If the user clicks two times the submit I show him a message and stop the second submit.

```
var submitted = false;
function disableForm(theform) {
       if (true == submitted) {
            alert("form already submitted... please wait...");
            return false;
        }
        else {            
            // here you close the dialog, open an other
            submitted = true;
            return true;
        }
}
```

I can not write how to close the dialog that you open since you do not have give any clue/code about it, but I think it will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using updatepanels. You will need handlers like this one and an image "LoadingImage"

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  
      Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandle);
          Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandle);
          function beginRequestHandle(sender, Args) {
    document.getElementById("LoadingImage").style.visibility = "visible";

          //Do something when call begins.
            }

    function endRequestHandle(sender, Args) {
    document.getElementById("LoadingImage").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
          </script>
```

What it does is it shows an image when ajax call starts and hide it when it completes. You can use an animated gif for your purpose.

Comment: This is done only on UpdatePanel (did not see that keyword on question) and also why to make it manually ? there is the UpdateProgress on UpdatePanell

Comment: Yeah they do but never found one working and the OP needs something like "loading", he must be using UpdatePanel as he talks about postback too.

Comment: Since I have asp.net with no ajax code I need to do it without ajax.